# Pager.js with Lazy Bindings

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, pager

I'm trying to use Pager.js to create a single page app.  I have the following structure:

```
#word/definition
#word/example
#word/synonym
```

So that `definition`, `example`, and so on are divs with `page` bindings:

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'word'}">
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'definition'}">
    <-- stuff goes here -->
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'example'}">
    <-- stuff goes here -->
```

and so on.

Now, as it happens, each word has a single ViewModel for all the routes, which gets served by a JSON server handler:

```
{ definition: "A blah blah blah"
, example: "Don't mess with Texas"
, synonym: "fubar"
}
```

**How do I load the ViewModel in such a way that the three routes "share" it?**  I tried loading it in as

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'word', withOnShow: getJsonWord}>
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'definition'}">
    <-- stuff goes here -->
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'example'}">
    <-- stuff goes here -->
```

where `getJsonWord` is a function that hits the server and slurps up JSON.  It gets triggered, and I see a JSON response.  But when I have the page structured like this, all of the child divs are visible, always.  Pager doesn't switch between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your current `getJsonWord` is doing jquery async ajax call, means the final JSON is not returned directly from the function call.

you need to wrap your ajax call for pager.js to inject a callback.

Javascript in your vm constructor

```
your_root_vm.getJsonWord = function(callback) {
  $.getJSON(your_url, function(data) { callback(data); });
};
```

For the other issue you mentioned that all views are visible, please provide a jsfiddle if it's possible.